# Android Compose Constraint Layout in a LazyColumn, in a NavHost: error - replace() called on item that was not placed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I have a large project where i was getting this exception - ***replace() called on item that was not placed.*** I was able to narrow the root of the problem to having **a Constraint Layout within a NavHost.** I created an extremely *simplified* project where it is reproducible. I emphasize simplified, bc the consraintlayout is not even used properly here, constraints not applied - that's on purpose, to simplify and show that it doesnt matter in this case (in the real project, all constraints in place)
[Github link to the simplified project here](https://github.com/dmitrish/WhyConstraintCrashesInNavHost)
Also, relevant code snippets below.
If I call the MainContent() directly, no issues. If i call thru NavHost, i get a crash when i scroll thru the lazycolumn.

Questions

1. Is there anything wrong with the code?
2. If this is a Compose bug, I tried with many different versions of libraries - it must have been there for a long time. I saw a couple of stackoveflow questions on this, but none of them related the crash to navhost - is navhost just one of the conditions where the bug manifests itself?

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: replace() called on item that was not
> placed
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$LookaheadPassDelegate.replace(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1569)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.lookaheadReplace$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:923)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded

[image]

and specifically this is the code in Layoutnode.kt from Compose:

```
internal fun lookaheadReplace() {
        if (intrinsicsUsageByParent == UsageByParent.NotUsed) {
            // This LayoutNode may have asked children for intrinsics. If so, we should
            // clear the intrinsics usage for everything that was requested previously.
            clearSubtreePlacementIntrinsicsUsage()
        }
        **lookaheadPassDelegate!!.replace()**
    }
```

Activity:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
           // MainContent() -- this works
            val navController = rememberNavController()
            // with NavHost, it crashes.
            NavHost(
                navController,
                startDestination =  NavRoutes.MainRoute.name
            ) {
                mainGraph()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main Graph:

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.mainGraph(
) {
    navigation(startDestination = MainNavOption.Main.name, route = NavRoutes.MainRoute.name) {
        composable(MainNavOption.Main.name){
            MainContent()
        }
    }
}
```

Main Content:

```
@Composable
fun MainContent() {
    WhyConstraintTheme {
        val listState = rememberLazyListState()
        // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
        ) {
            var listItems = mutableListOf<ElementHolder>()
            for (i in 1.rangeTo(149)) {
                listItems.add(ElementHolder(i.toString()))
            }
            BoxWithConstraints(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                LazyColumn(
                    state = listState,
                    contentPadding = PaddingValues(1.dp),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                ) {
                    items(listItems) { item: ElementHolder ->
                        ElementListItem(
                            element = item.itemDescription,
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Element H

@Composable
fun ElementListItem(
element: String,
) {

```
ConstraintLayout() {
    val (
        divider, year, description, image,
        overflow
    ) = createRefs()

    Text(
        text = "element:  {$element}",
        modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(year) {
            linkTo(
                start = parent.start,
                end = parent.end,
            )
        }
    )
}
```

}

Versions used (btw, tried with many different versions, going back to a number of previous versions)

> val material_version = "1.5.4"
> implementation ("androidx.compose.material:material:$material_version")
>
> ```
> implementation ("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$material_version")
> implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
> implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
> implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.1")
> implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.10.01"))
> implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
> implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
> implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
> implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
> implementation ("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.1")
> ```
>
> implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.5")

EDIT:
Another trigger for crash is AnimatedContent. If you wrap the LazyColumn with a constraint layout inside an AnimatedContent (instead of NavHost), same crash happens. So probably the ultimate root cause has something to do with animations inside both NavHost and AnimatedContent - a Composable inside NavHost has AnimatedContentScope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fix for the crash seems to be upgrading the `ConstraintLayout` from `1.0.1` to `1.1.0-alpha13`.

Comment: indeed works. Strange it took them so long. This is such a fundamental use case. I guess everyone just switched into columns and rows instead of constraint layouts.

Comment: Well it I'm actually not sure when it was fixed, it could have been fixed in any of the previous alpha releases. I just assumed that the fix would have come in the main compose library and I only tested new releases of those, while sticking to `ConstraintLayout` stable, `1.0.1`. It's only yesterday that I realized that there was an alpha version and I only tried the latest alpha.

Comment: alpha version resolve crash problem. but ui results different. snapshot tests fail. you see stable and alpha versions diffs with paparazzi snapshot test https://imgur.com/a/6V1c0io